# Массив в SQLite

Tags: массивы, sqlite, java-8

можно ли как-то добавить массив в таблицу SQLite? Можете, пожалуйста, предоставить пример кода(Java).

Comment: Ну, сериализуй в строку, например.

Comment: Идея хранения массива в sql сама по себе настораживает. Для этого обычно таблицы есть